# column concat by specific column pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two Datframes like

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],
'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']},
index=['j0', 'j1', 'j2'])

right = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A0', 'A2'],
'D': ['D0', 'D2', 'D3']},
index=['K0', 'K2', 'K3'])
```

i want to column bind by the 'A' column. how to achieve this ?
and i want to do this by pd.concat not pd.merge

Comment: Why not merge? :)

Comment: @Roelant I have 11 Dataframe like such Thats the reason

Comment: set column A as the index? otherwise what is supposed to happen with the indexes? or use merge with a loop?